# Top bar/Panel customization orange line

Tags: customization, panel, top-bar

I've been trying to customize the panel to my liking but I can't figure out how to remove or at least shorten the orange line that you see in the screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uypcQ.png)

This is the code that I've got so far:
#panel {
background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.25);
border-radius: 2em;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right:5px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#panel .panel-button {
color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
}

#panel .panel-button:hover {
background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.25);
color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
border-radius: 2em;
}

#panel .panel-button:active {
background-color: rgba(233, 84, 32, 1);
border-radius: 2em;
color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hi, I’m using 20.04